# birthday problem with the following question

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the minimum number of people required for having the possibility of two people having same birthday?

I had an argument with my teacher. My answer was 2. He said 23. I need a clarification on this.

Comment: See, for example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: This was asked by my teacher. I said him the answer 2. He said its 23.

Comment: Two, I think...

Comment: 23 people is for there to be a chance of **50%** two people share a birthday. But if your question only asks for _a possibility_, then of course it's 2.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Can you look at the edited one. I know this one is silly.

Comment: @PrabinKumarSahu I agree with you: the answer is $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My answer was $2$. He said $23$.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Calculating_the_probability), $23$ is the minimum number of people such that there is at least a $50\%$ chance of two people sharing a birthday. Your teacher was most likely referring to this, but worded the question wrong.

> What is the minimum number of people required for having the possibility of two people having same birthday?

Since no probability is specified, the answer is just $2$. With $2$ people, there's a possibility they have the same birthday - it's unlikely, but it can happen. It can't happen with just one person - so $2$ would be the minimum number of people needed.